# SQL creating XML

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I need to generate a file XML with SQL on Oracle database. I have trouble to find the write syntax

```
SELECT 
XMLParse(CONTENT '<company><siret></siret><type></type></company>'WELLFORMED),
(XMLELEMENT("file",
    XMLParse(CONTENT '<data>'WELLFORMED),
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("name",DECODE (INDIV.NAME, null, TRIM(INDIV.NAMEO), TRIM(INDIV.NAME)))),
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("nir",TRIM(INDIV.NIR))),
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("BIRTH",INDIV.DATE_BIRTH)),
    XMLParse(CONTENT '</data><file-formation>'WELLFORMED),
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("id",' ')),
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("statut",' ')),
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("title",' ')),
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("code",' ')), 
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("code-motif",' ')),
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("modalite",' ')),
    XMLParse(CONTENT '<place>'WELLFORMED),
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("code",' ')),
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("city",' ')),
    XMLParse(CONTENT '</place>'WELLFORMED),
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("date-start",' ')),
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("date-end",' ')),
    XMLParse(CONTENT '<orga>'WELLFORMED),
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("siret",' ')),
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("ra",' ')),
    XMLParse(CONTENT '</orga><beneficiaire>'WELLFORMED),
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("statut", DECODE (PRES.INSCRIT_PE, 1, 1, 2))),
    XMLParse(CONTENT '</modalite>'WELLFORMED),
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("time", ACT.HEURE)),
    XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("cost",' ')))),
    XMLParse(CONTENT '</file-formation></file></cpf:trainning>'WELLFORMED)
FROM 
    STAGIAIRE STAG
    INNER JOIN INDIVIDU INDIV 
    ON STAG.ID_INDIVIDU = INDIV.ID_INDIVIDU
    INNER JOIN PRESCRIPTION PRES 
    ON PRES.ID = STAG.ID
    INNER JOIN ACTION ACT
    ON ACT.ID_ACTION = PRES.ID_ACTION
    INNER JOIN PARCOURS PARC 
    ON PARC.ID = ACT.ID;
```

As you can see I have a lot of empty data in my final XML file but for the moment I just have the name in my XML... 
How can I add all my XMLELEMENT after the XMLAGG

To be more precise, I need to create the following XML. The first part `<company></company>` is the same for every XML document I'll create then for the second part `<file></file>` I need to have as many `<file>` as I will have `<file>` in my database

```
<company>
<siret></siret>
<type></type>
</company>

<file>
    <data>
        <name>DECODE (INDIV.NAME, null, TRIM(INDIV.NAMEO), TRIM(INDIV.NAME)</name>
            <nir>TRIM(INDIV.NIR)</nir>
            <birth> INDIV.DATE_BIRTH</birth>
    </data>
    <file-formation>
            <id></id>
            <statut></statut>
            <title></title>
            <code></code> 
            <code-motif></codeMotif>
            <modalite></modalite>
            <place>
                <code></code>
                <city></city>
            </place>
            <date-start></date-start>
            <date-end></date-end>
            <orga></orga>
            <siret></siret>
            <ra></ra>
            <beneficiaire>
                <statut> DECODE (PRES.INSCRIT_PE, 1, 1, 2)</statut>
            <time>ACT.HEURE</time>
            <cost></cost>
    </file-formation>
</file>
```

I understand my mistake so I add the XMLAGG before the `<file>` element but it's still not working... I should have a file with more than 3000 `<file>` and I just have one line...
I have trouble to find the right method

```
SELECT 
XMLParse(CONTENT '<company><siret></siret><type></type></company>'WELLFORMED),
XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("file",
    XMLParse(CONTENT '<data>'WELLFORMED),
    (XMLELEMENT("name",DECODE (INDIV.NAME, null, TRIM(INDIV.NAMEO), TRIM(INDIV.NAME)))),
    (XMLELEMENT("nir",TRIM(INDIV.NIR))),
    (XMLELEMENT("BIRTH",INDIV.DATE_BIRTH)),
    XMLParse(CONTENT '</data><file-formation>'WELLFORMED),
    (XMLELEMENT("id",' ')),
    (XMLELEMENT("statut",' ')),
    (XMLELEMENT("title",' ')),
    (XMLELEMENT("code",' ')), 
    (XMLELEMENT("code-motif",' ')),
    (XMLELEMENT("modalite",' ')),
    XMLParse(CONTENT '<place>'WELLFORMED),
    (XMLELEMENT("code",' ')),
    (XMLELEMENT("city",' ')),
    XMLParse(CONTENT '</place>'WELLFORMED),
    (XMLELEMENT("date-start",' ')),
    (XMLELEMENT("date-end",' ')),
    XMLParse(CONTENT '<orga>'WELLFORMED),
    (XMLELEMENT("siret",' ')),
    (XMLELEMENT("ra",' ')),
    XMLParse(CONTENT '</orga><beneficiaire>'WELLFORMED),
    (XMLELEMENT("statut", DECODE (PRES.INSCRIT_PE, 1, 1, 2))),
    XMLParse(CONTENT '</modalite>'WELLFORMED),
    (XMLELEMENT("time", ACT.HEURE)),
    (XMLELEMENT("cost",' ')))),
    XMLParse(CONTENT '</file-formation></file></cpf:trainning>'WELLFORMED)
FROM 
    STAGIAIRE STAG
    INNER JOIN INDIVIDU INDIV 
    ON STAG.ID_INDIVIDU = INDIV.ID_INDIVIDU
    INNER JOIN PRESCRIPTION PRES 
    ON PRES.ID = STAG.ID
    INNER JOIN ACTION ACT
```

Comment: "As you can see..." - you haven't shown us the final XML file you refer to, or the original data, or the output you actually want. Not sure what you expect us to be able to do without any information?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what your problem is here, but maybe this will help a bit, or help someone else.

I've used XMLAGG to aggregate a set of XMLELEMENTs, as in

```
SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("f1",v1),XMLELEMENT("f2", v2),...
```

I would start small and build on it.

Here's a small working example of some SQL to generate a fictional SOAP request:

```
SELECT 
  XMLROOT( 
    XMLELEMENT("soap:Envelope", 
              XMLATTRIBUTES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS "xmlns:xsi"
                              , 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS "xmlns:xsd"
                              , 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "xmlns:soap"),
      XMLELEMENT("soap:Body",
        XMLELEMENT("serviceName", XMLATTRIBUTES('http://myserver.com/TheWebService/' AS "xmlns"),
          XMLCONCAT(
            XMLELEMENT("cd" 
            , XMLCONCAT(
                (SELECT XMLAGG(
                          XMLELEMENT("G1"
                           , XMLELEMENT("E1", v1)
                           , XMLELEMENT("E2", v2)
                           , CASE WHEN v3 IS NOT NULL
                                  THEN XMLELEMENT("E3", v3)
                                  ELSE XMLELEMENT("E3"
                                        , XMLATTRIBUTES('true' AS "xsi:nil"), NULL)
                             END
                           , XMLELEMENT("E4", v4)))
                   FROM (SELECT 'v1' v1, 'v2' v2, 'v3' v3, 'v4' v4 FROM dual))
              )  -- XMLConcat
            )  -- cd
          )  -- XMLConcat
        )  -- serviceName
      )  -- soap:Body 
    )  -- soap:Envelope
    , VERSION '1.0'
  ).getclobval()
  FROM dual;
```

And the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <serviceName xmlns="http://myserver.com/TheWebService/">
      <cd>
        <G1>
          <E1>v1</E1>
          <E2>v2</E2>
          <E3>v3</E3>
          <E4>v4</E4>
        </G1>
      </cd>
    </serviceName>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Hope there is something here to answer your question.  You should be able to run this as is to generate an XML document. The key is to start small and tack on additional elements as needed.

Comment: what is it for the  XMLCONCAT ?

Comment: Thanks DCookie! it's really nice to work with a model. Awesome :D